# LINQ query on DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

Below code puts all the row indices of selected cells into a ListBox. It works well but looks cumbersome.

I wonder why the commented loop wont work.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    List<int> indices = new List<int>() { };
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgv.SelectedCells)
    {
        indices.Add(cell.RowIndex);
    }
    foreach (int rowindex in indices.Distinct())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(rowindex);
    }

    //The following loop attempts to do the same, but wont work. 
    //foreach (int rowindex in dgv.SelectedCells.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.RowIndex).Distinct())
    //{
    //    listBox1.Items.Add(rowindex);
    //}

}
```

Comment: Without knowing what's not working. Try casting SelectedCells to an IEnumerable<DataGridViewCell> `dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(x => x.RowIndex).Distinct()`

Comment: Thanks @energ1ser, You solved it!   I never used 'Cast' before.

Answer (score 6):

Try casting SelectedCells to an `IEnumarable<DataGridVewCell>` and it should work.

```
dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(x => x.RowIndex).Distinct()
```